# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute ' SeparableConv1D' while converting Keras to Core ML Model

Tags: keras, mnist, coreml

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/188-beginning-machine-learning-with-keras-core-ml) on machine learning with Keras and CoreML, and when I get to the point to run the following code and convert Keras model to the CoreML. I get:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SeparableConv1D'

where should I change to resolve this problem?

This is the code I run:

```
output_labels = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

coreml_mnist = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(
    'best_model.09-0.03.h5', input_names=['image'], output_names=['output'], 
    class_labels=output_labels, image_input_names='image')
```

and here is what I get in detail:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-8fa50f6bbeb9> in <module>()
     10 coreml_mnist = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(
     11     'best_model.08-0.03.h5', input_names=['image'], output_names=['output'],
---> 12     class_labels=output_labels, image_input_names='image')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.pyc in convert(model, input_names, output_names, image_input_names, input_name_shape_dict, is_bgr, red_bias, green_bias, blue_bias, gray_bias, image_scale, class_labels, predicted_feature_name, model_precision, predicted_probabilities_output, add_custom_layers, custom_conversion_functions)
    758                       predicted_probabilities_output,
    759                       add_custom_layers,
--> 760                       custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions)
    761 
    762     return _MLModel(spec)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.pyc in convertToSpec(model, input_names, output_names, image_input_names, input_name_shape_dict, is_bgr, red_bias, green_bias, blue_bias, gray_bias, image_scale, class_labels, predicted_feature_name, model_precision, predicted_probabilities_output, add_custom_layers, custom_conversion_functions, custom_objects)
    554                                            add_custom_layers=add_custom_layers,
    555                                            custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions,
--> 556                                            custom_objects=custom_objects)
    557     else:
    558         raise RuntimeError(

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras2_converter.pyc in _convert(model, input_names, output_names, image_input_names, input_name_shape_dict, is_bgr, red_bias, green_bias, blue_bias, gray_bias, image_scale, class_labels, predicted_feature_name, predicted_probabilities_output, add_custom_layers, custom_conversion_functions, custom_objects)
    207     # Build network graph to represent Keras model
    208     graph = _topology2.NetGraph(model)
--> 209     graph.build()
    210 
    211     # The graph should be finalized before executing this

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_topology2.pyc in build(self, is_top_level)
    748             self.insert_1d_permute_layers()
    749             self.insert_permute_for_spatial_bn()
--> 750             self.defuse_activation()
    751             self.remove_internal_input_layers()
    752 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_topology2.pyc in defuse_activation(self)
    508                 isinstance(k_layer, _keras.layers.Conv1D) or
    509                 isinstance(k_layer, _keras.layers.SeparableConv2D) or
--> 510                 isinstance(k_layer, _keras.layers.SeparableConv1D) or
    511                 isinstance(k_layer, _keras.layers.Dense)):
    512 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SeparableConv1D'
```

Comment: Which Keras version are you using?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro keras version  2.0.6

Comment: That tutorial does not use SeparableConv1D layers. Did you add these yourself? If not, the error message may be misleading. Which version of coremltools are you using?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans No, I didn't add anything. The problem was related to the Keras versione used in the requirements.txt of the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are using a version of `keras` that is unsupported by `coremltools`, as `SeparableConv1D` was added later than keras 2.0.6, you should upgrade keras to the latest version for this to work.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. In the project folder, there is a requirements.txt which contains keras==2.0.6, changing that to the latest Keras resolves the problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/188-beginning-machine-learning-with-keras-core-ml), and as others have mentioned the version of `keras` doesn't support `SeparableConv1D`.

However, just updating the version of `keras` without also updating `tensorflow` caused other errors in the jupyter notebook. I was able to directly install compatible versions of `keras` and `tensorflow` within the jupyter notebook using the `sys` module. As of writing, the latest version of `keras` is 2.2.4, and one compatible version of `tensorflow` (at least tested for the tutorial) is 1.7.0.

You can run the following python code to make the installation:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install tensorflow==1.7.0
!{sys.executable} -m pip install keras==2.2.4
```